# execute middlePermutation in under 12000ms

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm doing a task named `Simple Fun #159: Middle Permutation` on `codewars`.

The description is:

> You are given a string s. Every letter in s appears once.
>
> Consider all strings formed by rearranging the letters in s. After
>   ordering these strings in dictionary order, return the middle term.
>   (If the sequence has a even length n, define its middle term to be the
>   (n/2)th term.)

This is my code:

```
var alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

function permutator(inputArr) {
  var results = [];

  function permute(arr, memo) {
    var cur, memo = memo || [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      cur = arr.splice(i, 1);
      if (arr.length === 0) {
        results.push(memo.concat(cur).join(''));
      }
      permute(arr.slice(), memo.concat(cur));
      arr.splice(i, 0, cur[0]);
    }

    return results;
  }

  return permute(inputArr);
}

function middlePermutation(s) {
  var variants = [],
      numbers = [],
      result = [],
      string = s.split('');
  variants = permutator(string);

  //convert to numbers
  for (var i = 0; i < variants.length; i++) {
    var current = variants[i].split('');
    for (var k = 0; k < current.length; k++) {
      current[k] = alphabet.indexOf(current[k]) + 1;
    }
    numbers.push(parseInt(current.join('')));
  }
  //get final array
  for (var i = 0; i < variants.length; i++) {
    result[i] = [];
    result[i].push(variants[i]);
    result[i].push(numbers[i]);
  }

  result.sort();

  if ((result.length % 2) !== 0) {
    return result[Math.ceil(result.length/2)][0];
  } else {
    return result[(result.length/2)-1][0];
  }
}
```

I succesfully passed all sample tests but when I try to pass 100 tests I get an error:

> Passed: 5 Failed: 0 Errors: 1
>
> Process was terminated. It took longer than 12000ms to complete

I mean my code is actually working and solving the problem but it takes too much time. How can I solve this in less than 12000 ms?

Comment: for the first letter, choose the mid letter between the available ones. repeat.

Comment: Actually creating all permutations is not needed to get the solution. Also, `splice` is a relatively slow method because it must reassign values to different indexes. Avoid it. For the rest, asking for a solution of a codewars challenge feels like cheating.

Comment: I will try this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's think about 4 letters.

```
a b c d
```

Each letter gets an equal share of being first. That's `4! / 4 = 6` permutations each. So the 12th permutation will start with `ceil(12 / 6) = 2` that's the second letter

```
b
```

Now we have three letters left. The first permutation with `b` on the left is the seventh one. Each letter that's left gets an equal share of being second. That's `3! / 3 = 2` permutations each. So the 12 - 6 = 6th permutation (counting from the 7th) will have the `ceil(6 / 2) = 3rd` letter from the ordered set that excludes `b`:

```
a c d
    ^
```

Leading to:

```
b d
```

Now we have two letters left.

```
a c
```

The first permutation (counting from the 7th) with `d` after `b` on the left is the fifth. Each letter that's left gets an equal share of being third (detect a pattern here?). That's `2! / 2 = 1` permutation each. So the `12 - 6 - 4 = 2nd` permutation starting from the 5th after the 7th :) would have the `ceil(2 / 1) = 2nd` letter from our last set, `{a, c}`.

Final permutation:

```
b d c a
```

Now if you can understand and apply that, you've earned it!