# Simple Fun #159: Middle Permutation

Tags: python, math, permutation

### Task

You are given a string s. Every letter in s appears once.

Consider all strings formed by rearranging the letters in s. After ordering these strings in dictionary order, return the middle term. (If the sequence has a even length n, define its middle term to be the (n/2)th term.)

### The problem

Hey guys. I am totaly stuck... I`ve got an algorithm to calculate the answer in O(n). All basic tests are passed. But I constantly fail all tests, where the lenght of string equals 23,24,25. Some scary stuff happens, always like this:

'noabcdefgijklymzustvpxwrq' should equal 'nmzyxwvutsrqpolkjigfedcba'

'lzyxvutsrqonmeijhkcafdgb' should equal 'lzyxvutsrqonmkjihgfedcba'

I mean that it goes in the right direction, but suddenly mistakes. Give me a hint what I should check or what thing to fix. Thanks a lot!

P.S. This [execute middlePermutation in under 12000ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037994/execute-middlepermutation-in-under-12000ms?answertab=votes#tab-top) gave me the idea of solving

### Code

```
import math

def middle_permutation(string):
    ans, tmp = '', sorted(list(string))
    dividend = math.factorial(len(tmp)) / 2
    for i in range(len(tmp)):
        perms = math.factorial(len(tmp)) / len(tmp)
        if len(tmp) == 1:
            ans += tmp[0]
            break
        letter = tmp[math.ceil(dividend / perms) - 1]
        ans += letter
        tmp.remove(letter)
        dividend -= perms * (math.floor(dividend / perms))
    print(len(string))
    return ans
```

### Here are some basic inputs

```
Test.describe("Basic tests")
Test.assert_equals(middle_permutation("abc"),"bac")
Test.assert_equals(middle_permutation("abcd"),"bdca")
Test.assert_equals(middle_permutation("abcdx"),"cbxda")
Test.assert_equals(middle_permutation("abcdxg"),"cxgdba")
Test.assert_equals(middle_permutation("abcdxgz"),"dczxgba")
```

Comment: "calculate the ansver (sic) in O(1)" - an algorithm that loops over the input, like `sorted(list(string))` and `for i in range(len(tmp))` do, is at least `O(n)`. Calling `list(string)` alone makes your algorithm `O(n)` because `list` will loop over the whole string.

Comment: Note that we do not know any sample inputs nor their expected outputs – this prevents us from running and subsequently debugging your code. Please [edit] your question to include some sample inputs as well as their expected and actual outputs. See the [ask] page how to best help us help you.

Comment: Can you please clarify the task and problem? The task of "ordering these strings" is O(n), yet "the problem" claims there is an O(1) solution. What are "the basic tests"? Are there failing tests other than for lengths 23, 24, 25? Does the code succeed for lengths 21, 22 and 26, 27? Seeing how the code fails and is not documented at all, can you please describe how it is *supposed to work* in words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not far from a good answer.

Because of 0 versus 1 indexing, you should start with

`dividend = math.factorial(len(tmp)) // 2 - 1`

and then you choose a slightly off letter, replace your code with

`letter = tmp[dividend // perms]`

Also as everything is integer here, it's better to use 'a // b' instead of `math.floor(a / b)`.

All in all, here's a corrected version of your code:

```
def middle_permutation(string): 
    ans, tmp = '', sorted(list(string)) 
    dividend = math.factorial(len(tmp)) // 2 - 1 
    for i in range(len(tmp)): 
        perms = math.factorial(len(tmp)) // len(tmp) 
        if len(tmp) == 1: 
            ans += tmp[0] 
            break 
        letter = tmp[dividend // perms] 
        ans += letter 
        tmp.remove(letter) 
        dividend -= perms * (dividend // perms) 
    return ans
```

and just for the beauty of it, a generalization:

```
def n_in_base(n, base): 
    r = [] 
    for b in base: 
        r.append(n % b) 
        n //= b 
    return reversed(r)

def nth_permutation(s, n):
    digits = n_in_base(n, range(1, len(s)+1))
    alphabet = sorted(s)
    return ''.join(alphabet.pop(ri) for ri in digits)

def middle_permutation(s):
    return nth_permutation(s, math.factorial(len(s)) // 2 - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Never use `/` if you always want a integer variable. Instead, use `//`.

Everthing should be blamed on the division operator `/`. In python, it is for float, not for integers. Even for integers, i.e. `2/1`, it still returns a float number `2.0`.

When numbers are small, it rarely causes problems. But when you are dealing with big numbers, it can be disaster!! Take a example here:

```bash
>>> flt = factorial(24)/2
>>> flt
3.102242008666197e+23
>>> it = factorial(24)//2
>>> it
310224200866619719680000
>>> flt-it
0.0
>>> flt % factorial(23)
2.5852016738884945e+22
>>> it % factorial(23)
0
```

This is because small permutations of the divisor will be amplified in the mod operation. Maybe one argues that the divisor is an integer! However the float dividend makes the divisor a float too.